# I want to install a two gang outlet

Tags: electrical

This is in the basement and I want to install a two gang outlet just under a currrenlty run wire.  I am trying to figure out the correct components that I need.

I know I need

- a two gang outlet box (does metal vs plastic matter?)
- two outlets  (does it have to be GFCI?)
- romex wire

Should I get a junction box to use to splice off of the wire that is already there and run it over to the outlet?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, is it the existing wire you'll use to power your new outlets? If so, you probably don't have enough slack to be legal. So this forces the question: do you have access to either end of that wire?

Comment: There is a outlet for the other side of the wall a few studs over.  I was thinking about cutting the wire and putting the cut/splice inside a junction box and just attaching the three wires with a nut. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: best not to have splices in wires, get enough romex to reach from the existing box to the new box + slack and enough to make junctions ,  disconnect the exisitng wire from the existing box and run it to the new box,  and then run the new wire from the new box to the existing box.

Comment: Not sure if this is obvious (considering what I've seen on Holmes, it's not) but the junction box has to be accessible, i.e. you can't hide it under the wallboard.

Comment: What does this wire feed right now? General lights and receptacles, or something more specific?

Comment: Thanks For the feedback.  I ran the wire to the existing box and attached it to that outlet.